# programming a 2006 Chevy Malibu key

Tags: chevrolet, key

I have followed the steps several times to program my 2006 Chevy Malibu but for some reason the keys will not program and the security light does not go off I have also let it sit for more than 10 minutes the security light still doesn't go off are there any other suggestions or should I just try letting it wait longer for the key to try to program

Comment: What steps are you doing? Also are you sure you got the correct key. I realize it fits mechanically but if you didn't get the correct smart key it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Larry's question 'What are doing?' have you tried another one of your keys for the vehicle? With your second key, lock the doors with it via the lock. Then open the door with it via the lock. Does it work now? If not lock the doors with the button on the key. Unlock the the doors with the button on the key. Does it work now? The above little run around is because sometimes cycling the system can do a reset. If at the end of cycling the keys it will still not turn off your immobiliser to start the engine then you are having a problem with: 1. The chip in the key is either lost or corrupt, or 2. The inductance winding in the steering coluum has failed, or 3. The vehicles ECU has failed or the vehicles instrument panel has failed. If the system does not respond to the run around then you will need a system scan to establish the exact fault area.